# Conditions on correlation parameter for positive (semi) definitiveness of variance-covariance matrix

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Consider a 3-variate random vector normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance-covariance matrix
$$
\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \rho & \rho\\
\rho & 1 & \rho\\
\rho & \rho & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Could you help me to understand under which conditions on $\rho$ $\Sigma$ is positive semi-definite and under which conditions on $\rho$ $\Sigma$ is positive definite?

We know that $\rho\in [-1,1]$. Since $Det(\Sigma)=1-3\rho^2+2\rho^3$, we have that $Det(\Sigma)\geq 0$ iff $\rho\geq -0.5$. Is this sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two statements are equivalent

1. $\Sigma$ is positive definite
2. All eigenvalues of $\Sigma$ are positive

The eigenvalues of $\Sigma$ are $\{1-\rho, 1-\rho,1 + 2\rho\}$, which implies that we require

$$
1 - \rho > 0 ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ 1 + 2\rho > 0
$$

or equivalently

$$
-1/2 < \rho < 1
$$

For the semi-definite case you can change "$<$" by "$\leq$"

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach, note that you can write $\Sigma$ as
$$
\Sigma = \rho e'e + (1 - \rho)I, 
$$ with $I$ the identity matrix and $e = (1,1,1)'$. We can take $O$, the matrix that consist of the orthonamal vectors $e/\sqrt{3},u,v$ and note that rotating perservs the question and the new sigma matrix (it preserves the eigen values)
$$
\Sigma_2 = O'\Sigma O = 3 \rho \,\text{diag}(1,0,0) + (1 - \rho) I = \text{diag}(2\rho + 1, 1 - \rho, 1 - \rho)
$$ And we have found all roots and the other answer apply.